# What about when the Object inside the option type is destroyed?

Tags: delphi, option-type

I've been looking at the use of [Option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) type.

This means converting a function like:

```cs
Customer GetCustomerById(Int32 customerID) {...}

Customer c = GetCustomerById(619);
DoStuff(c.FirstName, c.LastName);
```

to return a option `Maybe` type:

```cs
Maybe<Customer> GetCustomerById(Int32 customerID) {...}
```

in my non-functional language, i then have to check if the return value is present:

```cs
Maybe<Customer> c = GetCustomerById(619);

if (c.HasValue)  
   DoStuff(c.Value.FirstName, c.Value.LastName);
```

And that works well enough:

- you know from the function signature whether it *can* return a `null` (rather than raising an exception)
- you are poked into checked the returned value before blindly using it

### But there's no garbage collection

But I'm not in C#, Java, or C++ with its RAII. I'm in Delphi; a native language with manual memory management. I will continue to show code examples in a *C#*-like language.

With manual memory management, my original code:

```cs
Customer c = GetCustomerById(619);
if (c != nil) 
{
   try  
   {
      DoStuff(c.FirstName, c.LastName);
   }
   finally
   {
      c.Free();
   }
}
```

gets converted to something like:

```cs
Maybe<Customer> c = GetCustomerById(619);
if (c.HasValue)
{
   try  
   {
      DoStuff(c.Value.FirstName, c.Value.LastName);
   }
   finally
   {
      c.Value.Free();
   }
}
```

I now have a `Maybe<>` holding onto a reference that is ***invalid***; it's *worse* than null because now the `Maybe` *thinks* it has valid contents, and the contents do have a pointer to memory, but that memory isn't valid.

I've traded a possible `NullReferenceException` to a random data-corruption crash bug.

Has anyone thought about this issue, and techniques to work around it?

### Add .Free to the Maybe

I have thought about adding a method to the struct called `Free`:

```cs
void Free()
{
   if (this.HasValue()) 
   {
      _hasValue = false;
      T oldValue = _value;
      _value = null;
      oldValue.Free();
   }  
}
```

Which does work if people call it; and know to call it; know why to call it; and know what they shouldn't be calling.

A lot of subtle knowledge to avoid a dangerous bug that i only introduced by trying to use an option type.

It also falls apart when the object being wrapped in the `Maybe<T>` is actually destroyed indirectly through a method not named canonical `Free`:

```pascal
Maybe<ListItem> item = GetTheListItem();
if item.HasValue then
begin
   DoStuffWithItem(item.Value);
   item.Value.Delete;
   //item still thinks it's valid, but is not
   item.Value.Selected := False;
end;
```

### Bonus Chatter

The `Nullable`/`Maybe`/`Option` type has virtue for when dealing with types that have no in-built *non-value* (e.g. records, integers, strings, where there is no in-built *non-value*).

If a function returns a non-nullable value, then there's no way to communicate the non-presence of a return result without using some special **sentinal** values.

```
function GetBirthDate(): TDateTime; //returns 0 if there is no birth date
function GetAge(): Cardinal; //returns 4294967295 if there is no age
function GetSpouseName: string; //returns empty string if there is no spouse name
```

The **Option** is used to avoid special sentinel values, and communicate to the caller what is really going on.

```
function GetBirthDate(): Maybe<TDateTime>;
function GetAge(): Maybe<Integer>;
function GetSpouseName: Maybe<string>;
```

### Not just for non-nullable types

The `Option` type has also gained popularity a way to avoid `NullReferenceExceptions` (or `EAccessViolation` at address $00000000) by separating **thing** with **no thing**.

Functions returning special, sometimes dangerous, sentinal values

```
function GetBirthDate(): TDateTime; //returns 0 if there is no birth date
function GetAge(): Cardinal; //returns 4294967295 if there is no age
function GetSpouseName: string; //returns empty string if there is no spouse name
function GetCustomer: TCustomer; //returns nil if there is no customer
```

Are converted to forms where the special, sometimes dangerous, sentinal values are impossible:

```
function GetBirthDate(): Maybe<TDateTime>;
function GetAge(): Maybe<Integer>;
function GetSpouseName: Maybe<string>;
function GetCustomer: Maybe<TCustomer>;
```

Callers are made to realize the function can return **no thing**, and they must o go though the hoop of checking for existence. In the case of types that already support being **null**, the `Option` gives us a chance to try to stop people from causing NullReference exceptions.

In functional programming languages it is much more robust; the return type can be constructed so it is **impossible** to return a `nil` - the compiler just won't allow it.

In procedural programming languages the best we can do is lock away the `nil`,  and make it impossible to reach. And in the process the caller has more robust code.

One could argue *"why not tell the developer to never make mistakes"*:

**Bad**:

```
customer = GetCustomer();
Print(customer.FirstName);
```

**Good**:

```
customer = GetCustomer();
if Assigned(customer)
   Print(customer.FirstName);
```

Just *get good*.

The problem is i want the **compiler** to catch these mistakes. I want mistakes to be harder to happen in the first place. I want a pit of success. It forces the caller to understand that the function might fail. The *signature* itself explains what to do, and makes dealing with it easy.

In this case we are implicitly returning two values:

- a  customer
- a flag indicating if the customer is really there

People in functional programming languages have adopted the concept, and it is a concept that people are trying to bring back into procedural languages, that you have a new type that conveys if the value is there or not. And attempts to blindly use it will give a compile-time error:

```
customer = GetCustomer();
Print(customer.FirstName); //syntax error: Unknown property or method "FirstName"
```

### Bonus Reading

If you want to learn more about attempts to use the functional `Maybe` monad in procedural languages, you can consult more thoughts on the subject:

- Oracle Java: [Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)
- Delphi Sorcery: [Never return nil? Maybe!](http://delphisorcery.blogspot.ca/2015/01/never-return-nil-maybe.html)
- [Removing Null from C#](https://www.pluralsight.com/tech-blog/maybe)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan When we don't want it to be; we're trying to *uninvent* nulls here. ([Option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type))

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is more like Swift Optional.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Let me explain. The goal is to disassociate a sentinal *"bottom"* value from from *"nothing"*. Rather than returning a TDateTime of `0`,or an integer of `0`, or a string that is `''`, or a reference that is `nil`, you return a *thing* that has both *"the value"*, or an indication of **no value**. Some people might have a function `GetBirthDate(DavidHeffernan): TDateTime` return the special bottom value `0` to indicate no birth date. In the same way, people might have a function `GetUser(DavidHeffernan): TUser` return the special sentinal value `nil` to indicate no user.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nullable and Optional have overlapping functionality. But also some subtle differences. In this case it is not only about having null as potential value, but preventing accidental usage of the null value - adding additional level of protection that Delphi compiler does not give you out of the box.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Like I said there are subtle differences. For instance Swift Optional is actually Nullable but with full protection Ian seeks. I cannot say what is exact behavior of C# Nullable, because I don't use C#.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The C# `Nullable<T>` was originally intended to allow types that are not nullable (e.g. strings, integers, records) to become *pseudo-nullable*. But it can accept any `<T>` type. In my case, i want to have a `Maybe<T:class>`, to have the compiler catch me where i might not be checking for a possible nil reference.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Reference types in C#, Java, and Delphi are already nullable, which is why people are trying to implement `Maybe` in Java, C#, and Delphi. We're not trying to add nullablity to reference types; you are  completely misunderstanding the problem domain.

Comment: Very probably I am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that can protect you from calling anything on your `Value` wrapped in `Maybe` is to extract value out of the `Maybe` variable clearing the `Maybe` content and using the result like you would normally use any object reference.

Something like:

```
  TMaybe<T> = record
  strict private
    FValue: T;
  public
    ...
    function ExtractValue: T;
  end;

function TMaybe<T>.ExtractValue: T;
begin
  if not _hasValue then raise Exception.Create('Invalid operation, Maybe type has no value');
  Result := FValue;  
  _hasValue = false;
  FValue := Default(T);
end;
```

And then you would be forced to Extract value in order to use it.

```
Maybe<ListItem> item = GetTheListItem();
if item.HasValue then
begin
   Value := item.ExtractValue;
   DoStuffWithItem(Value);
   Value.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `Maybe` in Delphi, as objects are reference types, so you can use `nil` object pointers, eg:

```
type
  TCustomer = class
  public
    customerID: Int32;
    FirstName, LastName: string;
  end;

function GetCustomerById(customerID: Int32): TCustomer;
begin
  ...
  if (customerID is found) then
    Result := ...
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

```
var
  c: TCustomer;
begin
  c := GetCustomerById(619);
  if c <> nil then
    DoStuff(c.FirstName, c.LastName);
end;
```

If the function needs to allocate a new object for return, eg:

```
function GetCustomerById(customerID: Int32): TCustomer;
begin
  ...
  if (customerID is found) then
  begin
    Result := TCustomer.Create;
    ...
  end else
    Result := nil;
  ...
end;
```

Then you have two choices for lifetime management (assuming the caller needs to take ownership of the object because it is not owned elsewhere).

1) you can call `Free` when you are done using the object:

```
var
  c: TCustomer;
begin
  c := GetCustomerById(619);
  if c <> nil then
  try
    DoStuff(c.FirstName, c.LastName);
  finally
    c.Free;
  end;
end;
```

2) you can use a reference-counted interface:

```
type
  ICustomer = interface
    ['{2FBD7349-340C-4A4E-AA72-F4AD964A35D2}']
    function getCustomerID: Int32;
    function getFirstName: string;
    function getLastName: string;
    property CustomerID: Int32 read getCustomerID;
    property FirstName: string read getFirstName;
    property LastName: string read getLastName;
  end;

  TCustomer = class(TInterfacedObject, ICustomer)
  public
    fCustomerID: Int32;
    fFirstName, fLastName: string;

    function getCustomerID: Int32;
    function getFirstName: string;
    function getLastName: string;
  end;

function TCustomer.getCustomerID: Int32;
begin
  Result := fCustomerID;
end;

function TCustomer.getFirstName: string;
begin
  Result := fFirstName;
end;

function TCustomer.getLastName: string;
begin
  Result := fLastName;
end;
```

```
function GetCustomerById(customerID: Int32): ICustomer;
begin
  ...
  if (customerID is found) then
  begin
    Result := TCustomer.Create as ICustomer;
    ...
  end else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

```
var
  c: ICustomer;
begin
  c := GetCustomerById(619);
  if c <> nil then
    DoStuff(c.FirstName, c.LastName);
end;
```

Comment: *"so you can use `nil` object pointers"*. That's what we're trying to get rid of;  people forget to check for `nil`.

Comment: That is hard to avoid in Delphi, since `class` and `interface` types are reference types.  So, unless you switch to `record` (similar to `struct` in C/C++) for everything, you have to deal with `nil`s. The alternative is to make `GetCustomerById()` never return a `nil`, have it throw an exception if the `customerID` is not found

Comment: Code shouldn't throw exceptions in non-exceptional circumstances. An improvement would be `TryGetCustomerByID(customerID)`. And it has the bonus on the caller being forced to reckon with the reality that *nothing* has returned. `Maybe<T:class>` is the other way to force the caller to reckon with the reality that *nothing* has returned. C#, Java, and C++ also have the reality of `nil` references; which is why my question is language agnostic. C# and Java already solve my question by having garbage collection. C++, along with Delphi, have the manual allocations and nulls.

Comment: @IanBoyd: C++ deals with automatic memory management via RAII and smart pointers. Delphi deals with it via ARC (auto reference counting), which does not apply to objects unless you use interfaces, or the nextgen compilers (iOS, Android, Linux).